# Change php while loop iterations for each screen size

Tags: php

I've created a php while function that puts, in the same row, 5 divs with the same content.
How can I change the number of iterations of this while function, from 5 to 4, when the screen size gets bellow 992px?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't hardcode your layout, better use CSS and let the browser handle it.

Comment: I have no problem with just css. The problem is that the divs get source info from mysql table so I had to create the iterations (and the info won't always be the same)

Comment: PHP is generally not aware of screen sizes. Remember that PHP runs on the server, before the page is loaded to the user. Maybe some custom-built class would help, but I would strongly suggest following @Marvin 's idea and go with CSS.

Comment: I'm not developer so I'm resolving the problems step by step. In this case I was thinking about something like creating a variable taking the value 5 for large screens and assuming 4 bellow 992px.  And use that variable in the while loop. But I don't know how to do it or if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

PHP by itself do not know anything about the Screen Size. You could use JavaScript to determine the Screen Size, set a Cookie an based on this cookie you can do your PHP stuff.

On remark if Cookies or JavaScript are disabled than this can not work and without JavaScript I do not see a possibility at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/)", it's a php class that makes it easy to detect if the client uses a mobile phone, a tablet or a desktop.